# Yii2 - Select2 items background color based on model status

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I use `Select2` to select one of the users. 
But users of my site can have two situations: `active` and `inactive`
The user status is specified by the ‍‍`status` property inside the `UserRegister` model

I want the background color of inactive users to be red.

i used this code in my `view` to get `firstname` and `lastname` of users and `Select2` widget will use the data in `$users`:

```php
$users = [];
$userModels = \common\models\UserRegister::find()->select(['id', 'firstname', 'lastname'])->all();
foreach ($userModels as $user) {
    $users[$user->id] = $user->firstname . ' ' . $user->lastname;
}
```

and it is `Select2` widget code:

```php
<?= $form->field($model, 'mobile_user_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $users,
    'options' => [
        'dir' => 'rtl',
        'placeholder' => 'Users...',
        'multiple' => false,
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'tags' => false,
        'allowClear' => true,
    ],
])->label('Users') ?>
```

Comment: you should use `templates`, check [this](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-templates)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this somehow using the `templating` plugin options as described in the official documentation [here](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-advanced). As there isn't any direct way to pass the additional data (e.g status in your case) in the widget, so you'll have to make a small change in your data array as below;

```
$users = [];
$userModels = \common\models\User::find()->select(['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'status'])->all();
foreach ($userModels as $user) {
    // append user status at the end of name separating with a '-' assuming that name will not contain any '-' or you can use any other special character.
    // this isn't a proper solution but as there isn't any direct way to pass additional data (e.g status) in the widget, so we are doing this
    $users[$user->id] = $user->firstname . ' ' . $user->lastname . "-". $user->status;
}
```

You'll need to add following code snippet in the start of your view file for the rendering of template

```
use yii\web\JsExpression;

$renderTemplate = "
function renderTemplate(user) {
    if (!user.id) {
        return '<div class=\"myOption\">' + user.text + '</div>';
    }
    // split the text attribute of the option into user name and user status separated by '-'
    var arr = user.text.split('-');
    var name = arr[0];
    var status = arr[1];

    // check status value and change background color accordingly
    if(status == '0') {
        var style = 'style=\"background-color:#d89c9c\"';
        return '<div class=\"myOption\" '+style+'>' + name + '</div>';
    } else {
        return '<div class=\"myOption\">' + name + '</div>';
    }
}
";

$escape = new JsExpression("function(m) { return m; }");
$this->registerJs($renderTemplate, $this::POS_HEAD);
```

And then finally add templating options in the widget

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $users,
    'options' => [
        'dir' => 'rtl',
        'placeholder' => 'Users...',
        'multiple' => false,
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'tags' => false,
        'allowClear' => true,
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression('renderTemplate'),
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('renderTemplate'),
        'escapeMarkup' => $escape
    ],
])->label('Users') ?>
```

You'll have your desired result by following the solution above. But you may face some style issues because of different background colors of options. So you may want to add following styles;

```
<style type="text/css">
    .select2-container--krajee .select2-selection--single {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .select2-results__option {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .myOption {
        padding: 6px 24px 6px 12px;
    }
</style>
```